# How to specify Entitlements.plist attributes in JavaFXPorts (GluonHQ)

Tags: ios, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I would like to add some associated-domains in Entitlements.plist in my JavaFXPorts project.
It seems that Entitlements.plist is created automatically each time i run the gradle build under ./build/javafxports/tmp/ios/Entitlements.plist.

I would like to include the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
        <array>
                <string>applinks:example.com</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are right, the file is generated on every run. So far it only allows adding the `aps-environment` for push notifications, as you can see [here](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/src/811de9a1c490ebc2693cf952d2c27aba2921129b/src/main/groovy/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/plugin/ios/task/BaseIosTask.groovy#lines-329). A quick workaround in your case will be cloning the jfxmobile plugin, adding your requirements to that method, building the plugin and using a local snapshot in your project.

Comment: @JoséPereda any chance to add it as parameter in a near future release?

Comment: For Java 8/9 I don't think so, the work now is focused on getting it working with 11. Anyway, could you file an [issue](https://github.com/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/issues) with the details of the API required?

Comment: Yes of course. I have cloned and built the repository locally. However I get the following error:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Gradle_iOS'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'JFXMobilePlugin'.
      > com/android/build/gradle/internal/dsl/SigningConfig
Any feedback on this?

Comment: Building the plugin is fairly easy (`./gradlew build` or `./gradlew install`), and applying  it just requires adding `mavenLocal()` and the snapshot version 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT to the buildscript. Make sure you clean your project and update its gradlew wrapper to 4.3.1 or alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have found a work around on how to include more Entitlements in JavaFXPorts with robovm. I am giving an example below

Create **robovm.xml** in *src/ios/* directory and define the **Entitlements.plist** location as below.

> robovm.xml ([See document](http://robovm.mobidevelop.com/docs/en/configuration.html))

```
<config>
   <iosEntitlementsPList>assets/Entitlements.plist</iosEntitlementsPList>
</config>
```

Then define the **robovm.xml** location in **build.gradle**.

> build.gradle ([See document](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_ios_4))

```
jfxmobile {
    javafxportsVersion = '8.60.11'
    ios {
        ...
        configFile = file('src/ios/robovm.xml')
    }
}
```

Running the build now will include any Entitlements you have defined in **src/ios/assets/Entitlements.plist**

Comment: Great, looks good. Just in case you want to complete the answer, can you add the references to the JavaFXPorts [docs](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_ios_4) and Mobidevelop [docs](http://robovm.mobidevelop.com/docs/en/configuration.html)? I take that the entitlements added to that custom plist file are _added_ to the generated entitlements.plist file?

Comment: @JoséPereda yes, exactly. The entitlements in custom plist are appended in the one created under build/javafxports/tmp/ios/Entitlements.plist. Hope you’ll support this in GluonVM as well